# Access to bare option when using Coffeescript.compile

Tags: coffeescript

I am using [coffee-script.js](http://coffeescript.org/#scripts) to let me compile little snippets of coffeescript into javascript inside the browser. This lets me do:

```
eval(Coffeescript.compile("console.log 'yo'"))
```

But this returns a wrapped function, like this:

```
(function() {

  console.log('yo')

}).call(this);
```

I would like to get an unwrapped snippet of code, so that I can call functions that would be in scope if it wasn't for the function wrapper. Any suggestions apart from a regex to strip it out by hand?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pass the `bare` option in the second argument of `compile`:

```
// In JS
CoffeeScript.compile("console.log 'yo'", {bare: true})

# In CS :)
CoffeeScript.compile "console.log 'yo'", bare: on
```

But you could also use [`CoffeeScript.eval`](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/blob/cc1b056b03a12ada575efdeb7b2a930f51eae33d/src/browser.coffee#L11) directly. It will do just what you're looking for :)

Comment: Is there a place where these options are documented?

Comment: Good question. I didn't find any official documentation, just come up with the `bare` option from reading the [#usage](http://coffeescript.org/#usage) section in coffeescript.org and toying around with the CoffeeScript object on the Node (or the browser) console.

Comment: I bought a little book and found it helpful: http://arcturo.github.com/library/coffeescript/index.html

Comment: The list of all the valid option flags that coffee knows how to handle: http://coffeescript.org/documentation/docs/command.html#section-5